# Delete object inside the class C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor

There is a part of my class, which I'm using to read data, byte by byte, until `'\0'` occur.

```
RESULT MyClass::readMethod(DataInputStream& s)    
{
    if ( condition = ok )
    {   
        char tmp[32];
        uint8 i = 0;
        do {
            tmp[i] = s.read_int8();
        } while (tmp[i++] == '\0');

        char *arr= new char[i];

        for (uint8 j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            arr[j] = tmp[j];
        }
        //delete[] arr;
    }
}
```

I removed a lot of code for this post, since rest is less important.
My problem is, that I want to free up memory, but since I've got method:

I tried put it into destructor:

```
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    delete [] arr;
}
```

but compiler (I use Visual Studio 2010) underline it and says: `"Error: identifier arr is undefined".`
I can't use it in place where it is commented, because I've got following method:

```
char * getArr()
{
    return arr;
}
```

But tbh, I don't know if it will work, I mean, if I can access `arr` outside the class. Im still learning C++ and OOP, and sometimes I'm confused.
Similiar problem is with constructor: how to initialize `arr` to be empty.

Comment: How long is `arr` supposed to remain valid? Who is responsible for deleting it? If the class is responsible, then the class needs to save a copy of it somewhere so it can delete it later. (Why is this tagged `C`?)

Comment: if not needed, avoid using pointers and in this case use `std::string`. and `arr` is unknown to the destructor because it is a local variable of `readMethod()`

Comment: how does `char * getArr() { return arr; }` compile if you don't have a member called `arr` ?

Comment: `char *arr= new char[i];` is local to `readMethod()`. Make it a class member variable, to access it from other member functions of the class.

Comment: `arr` is array for storing PIN code. It should remain as long as someone decide to delete it and change PIN (delete `arr`, and make another one) - that's why I wanted to use destructor.  
I don't know who should be responsible for it, that's one of the problems.  
How to make a copy somewhere to delete it later?  
I removec 'c' tag, sorry, clicked 'suggested' propably.

Comment: When dealing with raw pointers, you always should have a clean concept of ownership. Who is responsible for allocating and deleting the memory? How long is it supposed to remain valid? You are providing the `getArr()` method but how do you ensure that the returned memory is not used after your `MyClass` instance goes out of scope and thus frees the memory? You might be better off using a std::string here and pass/return it by value. Or maybe use smart pointers.

Comment: Actually, πάντα ῥεῖ suggested pretty good solution. I'm not using std::string, because it's part of a bigger project and I'm not allowed to (just no :( ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arr is local to readMethod. So the destructor does not know it. You have to declare arr as a class member.

```
class MyClass
{

  private:
     char* arr;
}
```

Then you can delete it in your destructor.

Comment: That's right, thank you. Since I was working on it so long, I forgot to modify .h file with class declaration.  
BTW I'm so sad that's a lot of my C++ posts are getting downvoted and I don't know why, so I can't make better posts :(

Comment: @Kappa _"... so I can't make better posts"_ You may want to [**read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, before posting your next question.